# How do I fill up a massive hole in the world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Due to some issues on my server, I was forced to remove a massive hole of about 100k blocks on my server.

[image: Massive Hole]

The problem is, it is really close to the spawn and I don't want anyone seeing it. Is there any way to cover it up?

I have tried using WorldEdit and my server crashes. Is there any way to cover it up that doesn't involve taking an hour?

Comment: I would recommend placing a thin 2-block-thick layer of dirt over the hole, and putting up a sign that says "No digging." That should take care of it; I can't see how it could go wrong.

Comment: If anything, anyone who *does*... *User fell out of the world*

Comment: @Wikwocket This would work if you used glass instead of dirt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the moment there are chunks that are filled with air.

If you go into MCEdit (for example) you can **remove** the offending chunks and then when you reload the world they will regenerate.

In MCEdit use the selection tool to highlight the offending chunks then click "Select Chunks" followed by "Chunk Control". Then use the "Delete" option. Save and quit.

You can tell if the chunks are still there as there will be a checkerboard "background" in MCEdit. If the chunk is missing completely the background will be blue.

As MBreadley points out you should take the Minecraft server offline before using another program to edit the world.

Comment: One thing to note: **Take the server offline before editing!**  Having two programs (MCEdit and the Minecraft server) writing to the same files is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @MBraedley Good point!

Comment: The server and MCEdit both honour the world lock file, but that just avoids nasty corruption. One or the other will still be unhappy and throw a fit if the lock file is taken away by the other program.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Bukkit it's as simple as using this [regen chunks mod](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/edit-chunkregen-v1-0-regenerate-your-world-bit-by-bit-953.25843/). It allows you to just `/regen` the chunk you're in. Use with care!